# url rewriting in php using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-1.3

I need to rewrite the url in my project.

I have a url like this

```
http://www.example.com/apps?platform=Android&category=Business&keyword=cows
```

and i need to rewrite this to `http://www.example.com/apps/Android-Business-cows`

How can i implement this url rewrite

I am cakephp framework in php.

Comment: what have you tried? This website is overflowing with answers to your question

Comment: yes but all i have is rewrite url by including parameters also, but here i don't need to include the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(apps)/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)/?$ $1?platform=$2&category=$3&keyword=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do (asuming you're using mod-rewrite on apache):

```
RewriteEngine ON
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteRule ^apps/([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$ apps?platform=$1&category=$2&keyword=$3
```